# Does anyone know how to fix images margins in email signature in office 365?

Tags: html, image, office365, signature, margins

Outlook office 365 adds 5 px margin to images in email signature table. Does anyone know how to prevent/fix that?
Fixing from [this link](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/two_fixes_for_image_spacing_in_outlook_web_app_owa) doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here how to get rid of the 5px margin added to images in email signature table:

http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/two_fixes_for_image_spacing_in_outlook_web_app_owa

just add align:left;